# Leave one out cross validation by leaving out two ID during the training process

Tags: r, cross-validation

I have a dataframe `df`

```
df<-structure(list(ID = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9), Y = c(2268.14043972082, 2147.62290922552, 
2269.1387550775, 2247.31983098201, 1903.39138268307, 2174.78291538358, 
2359.51909126411, 2488.39004804939, 212.851575751527, 461.398994384333, 
567.150629704352, 781.775113821961, 918.303706148872, 1107.37695799186, 
1160.80594193377, 1412.61328924168, 1689.48879626486, 685.154353165934, 
574.088067465695, 650.30821636616, 494.185166497016, 436.312162090908
), P = c(1750.51986303926, 1614.11541634798, 951.847023338079, 
1119.3682884872, 1112.38984390156, 1270.65773075982, 1234.72262170166, 
1338.46096616983, 1198.95775346458, 1136.69287367165, 1265.46480803983, 
1364.70149818063, 1112.37006707489, 1346.49240261316, 1740.56677791104, 
1410.99217295647, 1693.18871380948, 275.447173420805, 396.449789014179, 
251.609239829704, 215.432550271042, 55.5336257666349), A = c(49, 
50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 14, 15, 16, 17, 163, 
164, 165, 153, 154), TA = c(9.10006221322572, 7.65505467142961, 
8.21480062559674, 8.09251754304318, 8.466220758789, 8.48094407814006, 
8.77304120569444, 8.31727518543397, 8.14410265791868, 8.80921738865237, 
9.04091478341757, 9.66233618146246, 8.77015716015164, 9.46037931956657, 
9.59702379240667, 10.1739258740118, 9.39524442215692, -0.00568604734662462, 
-2.12940164413048, -0.428603434930109, 1.52337963973006, -1.04714984064565
), TS = c(9.6499861763085, 7.00622420539595, 7.73511170298675, 
7.68006974050443, 8.07442411510912, 8.27687965909096, 8.76025039592727, 
8.3345638889156, 9.23658956753677, 8.98160722605782, 8.98234210211611, 
9.57066566368204, 8.74444401914267, 8.98719629775988, 9.18169205278566, 
9.98225438314085, 9.56196773059615, 5.47788158053928, 2.58106090926808, 
3.22420704848299, 1.36953555753786, 0.241334267522977), R = c(11.6679680423377, 
11.0166459173372, 11.1851268491296, 10.7404563561694, 12.1054055597684, 
10.9551321815546, 11.1975918244469, 10.7242192465965, 10.1661703705992, 
11.4840412725324, 11.1248456370953, 11.2529612597628, 10.7694642397996, 
12.3300887767583, 12.0478558531771, 12.3212362249214, 11.5650773932264, 
9.56070414783612, 9.61762902218185, 10.2076240621201, 11.8234628013552, 
10.9184029778985)), .Names = c("ID", "Y", "P", "A", "TA", "TS", 
"R"), na.action = structure(77:78, .Names = c("77", "78"), class = "omit"), row.names = c(NA, 
22L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am currently doing a linear regression in leave one cross validation mode. In other words, during the training I remove one site for each iteration and test the model on the site left out. See below the procedure:

```
df$prediction <- NA
for(id in unique(df$ID)){
  train.df <- df[df$ID != id,]
  test.df <- df[df$ID == id, c("P", "A", "TA", "TS","R")]
  lm.df<- glm(Y ~ P+A+TA+TS+R, data=train.df)
  step.df<- step(lm.df, direction = "backward")
  df.pred = predict(object = step.df, newdata = test.df)
  df$prediction[df$ID== id] <- df.pred
}
```

However, I would like to remove 2 IDs for each iteration during the cross validation instead of one. Therefore, my test set will contain two IDs instead of one every time. Anyone know how I could do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change `==` into `%in%` and `unique(df$ID)` into `split(unique(df$ID), c(1,1,2,2,3))` it seems to be working. Essentially, in each iteration you pass two ids instead of one, so the test.df set contains those two.

See this:

```
df$prediction <- NA
for(id in split(unique(df$ID), c(1,1,2,2,3))){
  print(id)
  train.df <- df[!df$ID %in% id,]
  test.df <- df[df$ID %in% id, c("P", "A", "TA", "TS","R")]
  lm.df<- glm(Y ~ P+A+TA+TS+R, data=train.df)
  step.df<- step(lm.df, direction = "backward",trace=0)
  df.pred = predict(object = step.df, newdata = test.df)
  df$prediction[df$ID %in% id] <- df.pred
}
```

Output:

```
[1] 4 5
[1] 6 8
[1] 9
```

I have set trace to zero above so that it only prints the ids passed in the loop. As you can see you have two instead of one (apart from the last one obviously). `split` splits the vector `unique(df$ID)` in 2-element pieces which we can then use within the loop.